# Line of code from Swift to Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I'm quite blank when it comes to swift, I've been developing using Obj-c. But a tutorial that I've been following uses Swift. Can anyone help me convert the following line of Swift into Objective-C. It's basically to load a String onto an Array.

```
self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
```

Comment: Can you add the lines that show iDArray & objectIDs types and constructions?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
```

Should be

```
[self.iDArray append: [objectIDs[1].valueForKey: @"objectID"]]
```

However, the Swift code is force-casting `[objectIDs[1].valueForKey: @"objectID"]` to type String (A Swift string).

That suggests to me that self.iDArray may be a Swift array. Swift arrays normally contain only a single type. You create an array of String objects, or an array of Dictionary objects. You can also create an array of `AnyObject`.

NSArray is an array of `id` type.

I'm not 100% positive how to force-cast to String type in Objective-C. maybe:

```
[self.iDArray append: (String) [objectIDs[1] valueForKey: @"objectID"]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response :). I gave it a shot and I'm getting the following error. Property 'valueForKey' not found on object of type 'id'. Also I'm using an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Can you post a complete test case? This would help.

Comment: It's a typo. Replace the `.` ahead of `valueForKey:` with a space.

Comment: @JohnDifool : It's to stream audio files from Parse. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OM_UJWAQ3Js

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad: trying it

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad -  Clever, but that will crash at runtime, since `somePFObject[@"objectId"]` will be null, and the OP appears to be inserting into an array.

Comment: Well, I assumed that there is always an object ID. The identifier sounds like this.

Comment: To deal with `nil`s in Obejctive-C you can simply use the `?:` operator and pass a different value (`[NSNull null]`?) in case of `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface, objectIDs[x] appears to be a dictionary, and the compiler will give you a break on types if you dereference it that way.  So naive to parse, a usable syntax would be:

```
[self.iDArray append:objectIDs[1][@"objectId"]];
```

**But** that's incorrect semantically for parse, since the implication is that the objectIDs array is implied to contain parse objects (named confusingly with the "IDs" suffix).  If it's really parse objects, then the collection style reference for objectId won't work, and should be instead

```
[self.iDArray append:((PFObject *)objectIDs[1]).objectId];
```

Or more readably:

```
PFObject *object = objectIDs[1];
NSString *objectId = object.objectId;
[self.iDArray append:objectId];
```

**But**, along the same lines semantically, the implication of the code is that it's adding to an NSMutable array, so it probably should be -- for any of the above suggestions:

```
[self.iDArray addObject: .....
```

Stop reading here if you care only about compiling and executing without a crash.

**But**, even if all that's right, which I think can be inferred from the code, it's indicative of bad design in my opinion.  Swift developers in particular seem to have a penchant for saving off objectIDs and passing them around as proxies for object, and in so doing, loosing all of the other valuable stuff in the PFObject.

My practice is, wherever possible, just keep and pass the whole PFObject.  You can always ask it for its objectId, later.  More strongly, my rule of thumb when reading code is: show me parse.com code that refers much to objectIds -- except for things like equality tests -- and I'll show you a design error.

Comment: Hey! Impressed :D. So, I've been trying around, i've managed to get the objectId from Parse as a string. Now I'm trying to insertObject: atIndex:. Seems to be fine until I try to Log the array and get (null) as the array

Comment: Hopefully you get objetId the sanctioned way with `.objectId`, and consider the insertion as `addObject:` which is much more like append than insertObject:atIndex (unless the index is count-1, in which case they are identical and addObject is more concise).

Comment: Alright, going with addObject. But clearly I'm doing something wrong, if I NSLog [iDArray objectAtIndex:1] I get (null)      :(

Comment: That's equivalent to iDArray[1], and it means the problem is upstream somewhere, where that array is supposed to be filled.